# Let $Q$ be orthogonal matrix and $v,u$ be vectors. Show that $Qu \cdot Qv = u \cdot v$

Tags: linear-algebra, solution-verification, alternative-proof

> Suppose $Q$ is orthogonal $n$ by $n$ matrix and $v,u$ are vectors in $\mathbb R^n$. Show that
>   $$Qu \cdot Qv = u \cdot v$$

My attempt:

We will denote arbitrary element of $Q$ as $q_{ij}$

So

$$Qv =  \begin{pmatrix}
\sum_{i}^{n}q_{1i}v_i\\ 
\cdots\\ 
\sum_{i}^{n}q_{ni}v_i
\end{pmatrix} $$

and

$$Qu =  \begin{pmatrix}
\sum_{i}^{n}q_{1i}u_i\\ 
\cdots\\ 
\sum_{i}^{n}q_{ni}u_i
\end{pmatrix} $$

Hence

$$\begin{align}Qu \cdot Qv & = \sum_{j=1}^{n}\biggr(\sum_{i=1}^{n}q_{ji}u_i \sum_{i=1}^{n}q_{ji}v_i\biggl ) \\
& = \sum_{j=1}^{n}\sum_{i=1}^{n}q_{ji}^2v_iu_i \\ 
& = \sum_{i=1}^{n}\sum_{j=1}^{n}q_{ji}^2v_iu_i = \sum_{i=1}^{n}\underbrace{\sum_{j=1}^{n}q_{ji}^2}_{= 1}v_iu_i = u \cdot v \\ 
\end{align}$$

$\blacksquare$

1. Is it correct?
2. Is there a better way to prove it?

Comment: Note that $$\sum_{i=1}^n q_{ji}u_i\sum_{i=1}^nq_{ji}v_i \neq \sum_{i=1}^n q_{ji}^2 v_iu_i$$ on the level of algebraic formulas, so unless you specifically have a theorem showing this is true for orthogonal matrices, you need to show more work here.

Comment: @BrianMoehring I don't have the theorem, actually. I've just made a careless mistake that coincidentally led me to the correct result. Thanks for pointing that out.

Comment: It's not correct. Use different (dummy) labels in the sums to realize where your mistake is

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since $Q$ is orthogonal, $QQ^T=Q^TQ=I$. Therefore,

$$Qu\cdot Qv:= (Qu)^T(Qv)=u^TQ^TQv=u^Tv=u\cdot v$$